# Cannot Resolve Symbol SetLayoutManager - Android

Tags: android

I am trying to set up the view for one of my java classes.  I am getting an error on SetLayoutManager and Linear LayoutManager. I am a beginner so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class CrimeListFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mCrimeRecyclerView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime_list, container, false);

        mCrimeRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.crime_recycler_view);
        mCrimeRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the stacktrace with the error ?

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
...
mCrimeRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.crime_recycler_view);
mCrimeRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
LinearLayoutManager mL = new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext());
mCrimeRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mL);
```

Comment: This did not work.  I still get "cannot resolve symbol" error